# Set up a form control that updates when a value in a combo box is selected

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box on an Order Entry Form I designed that allows me to select from a dropdown of Company Names from a table entitled tblCustomers.  The row source for this control is:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM tblCustomers;
```

The bound column is 1 so that I can store the CustomerID in the underlying tblOrders table.

My question is:

I would like a text box on the form that displays the SalesPerson (which is also in the tblCustomers table) associated with the Customer chosen in the combo box.

Comment: I figured it out.  I used:

Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate()
    Dim CustID As Long
    CustID = Me.Customer
    
    Me.SalesRep = (DLookup("SalesPerson", "tblCustomers", "CustomerID=" & CustID))
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the column property in combos:

If the row source of your combo is:

```
 SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, SalesPerson FROM tblCustomers;
```

You can set the control source of a textbox to refer to column property, counting from zero:

```
 =ComboX.Column(2)
```

You will need to set the column count to 3.

Comment: That is a good idea also.  Would you typically prefer that to a DLookup in VBA?  Or given the choice do you always go the "code route"?

Comment: You can set the control source of the textbox as illustrated, it is faster than DLookup because the data is already there in the combobox. For the most part, a huge advantage of MS Access is that you do not have to write any code to do quite a lot.