# How to see name when I enter an id in access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a Form where I Enter **CustomerID** in a combo box. This box has Two Columns CustomerID and CustName.

the CustName and CustFather reside in another query.

is there a way to show the CustName and CustFather everytime i enter CustomerID in the form?

The CustomerID is entered in a form and not in the same table as CustName and CustFather.

Tried DLookup but it just looks only the first time and then shows that same value everytime i open the form or update it. the dlookup is shown as:

```
=DLookUp("CustName","qryForRecovery","CustomerID =" & "CustomerID")
```

is there a way i can show the CustName everytime i update the CustomerID field?

This is the link to the snapshot of my recovery form. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzuxK.png

Comment: You tried what? Show your effort. Maybe an image is exceptionally usefull (from the populated form). Add recordsource bound/unbound fieldsand the dlookup  to question. And read [ask] and related.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944351/78522

Comment: Every entry means a continuous-form? ID field is bound?

Comment: Don't know anything. I've edited the question and added an image link. can you please Help?

Comment: That won't work, as you don't refer to the control`CustomerID`, yout criteria looks is "CustomerID=CustomerID", what gets true, so first value of query is displayed. You have to refer to the crontrol by ommiting the double-quotes from last CustomerID.`"CustomerID=" & CustomerID`, what gets`CustomerID=2` for your image.

Comment: But you can use`=ComboBox.Colunm(1)`like @PatrickHonorez suggested. If you don't know what a coninuous-form or a bound control is, query the web, as they are important

Comment: @ComputerVersteher  and Patrick Honorez thank you brother.  You guys  made a very difficult thing easy for me. ComboxName.Column(1) worked.

Comment: You're welcome! Don'r forget to vote (arrow up) for Patricks answer. Keep in mind to delete your thank you comments after they are received (like above). If you update your questiom (add final solution to end and [improve formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ),it gets my vote .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combo box to enter the customerId.
Then create a text box for the customerName, that links to the customerId combo, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944351/78522).
The trick is to properly set the properties of the combo:
`RowSource Type`: Table/Query
`Source`: `SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM tblCustomers`
`Bound column`: 1
`Column count`: 2
`Limit to List`: Yes
`Column widths`: 3;0  'second column will be hidden

Comment: Doesn't work. The expression Builder turns Combox.Column(2) into [Combox].[Column](2)

Comment: @MalikSahab should be`ComboBox.Column(1)`as columns are zero-based (first column is .Column(0)). The addition of square-brackets is ok, but not needed if no specialchars or reserved names used(like ComboBox).

Comment: @Patrick Honorez thank you. May God make your life easier as you made mine.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Dlookups or whatever ..just correctly designed ComboBox
**RowSource** = SELECT CustomerID,CustName CustFath From Customers
**Bound column**: 1
**Column count**: 3
**Column width** : 0;4;4
You won't see the ID ..but Customer Name will be nicely displayed.